# Plane Geometry - Proof by Contradiction?

Tags: geometry

In a trapezium $ABCD$, $AB||CD$ and $AB<CD$. Given that $AC+BC=AD+BD$, prove that $AD=BC$.

I have a feeling that a proof by contradiction is possible, but to me the result just seems obvious and I have been going round and round in circles trying to find a rigorous proof. Any suggestions?

Comment: prove that it is an parallelogram

Comment: how would that be possible?

Comment: because it is a parallelogram (no other parallel trapezium has  AC+BC=AD+BD ) so start that is is not a parallelogram get into a contradiction and you have proved it is a parallelogram, and the rest is simple

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- Consider an [ellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse) $\mathcal{E}$ with foci at $A$ and $B$, and passing through point $C$.
- From properties of ellipse we know that for any point $X \in \mathcal{E}$ we have $AX + BX = AC + BC$, in particular $D \in \mathcal{E}$.
- Finally, ellipses are symmetrical along their axes.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thanks, this really helped.
However, I was wondering if a purely synthetic solution is possible, especially since the problem itself looks rather simple.

Comment: Which part of this approach is not synthetic enough for you?